# Missing required attribute: dependency groupId while using flutter module .aar file in android

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-plugin, flutter-module

I have integrated flutter plugin inside flutter module and it is working fine as expected but when an .aar file is generated and imported in another android app below error apprears

Missing required attribute: dependency groupId

I have  integrated the aar in the following way (according to official flutter documentationhttps://docs.flutter.dev/development/add-to-app/android/project-setup#option-a---depend-on-the-android-archive-aar),

1. Open /app/build.gradle
2. Ensure you have the repositories configured, otherwise add them:

   String storageUrl = System.env.FLUTTER_STORAGE_BASE_URL ?: "https://storage.googleapis.com"
   repositories {
   maven {
   url '/home/reddy/AndroidStudioProjects/sdkmodule/build/host/outputs/repo'
   }
   maven {
   url "$storageUrl/download.flutter.io"
   }
   }
3. Make the host app depend on the Flutter module:

```
dependencies {
  debugImplementation 'com.npst.sdkmodule:flutter:1.0:debug'
  profileImplementation 'com.npst.sdkmodule:flutter:1.0:profile'
  releaseImplementation 'com.npst.sdkmodule:flutter:1.0:release'
}
```

4. Add the `profile` build type:

```
android {
  buildTypes {
    profile {
      initWith debug
    }
  }
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated?